# How can we do Emacs like indenting in VSCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emacs

How can we do auto-indenting of the code in VSCode editor? In Emacs I could select all and press TAB for this purpose.

Comment: You could do a `Format Selection` Ctrl+K Ctrl+F

Comment: @Metropolis how is this a better fit there? The question is about VSCode, not emacs.